# Use NGINX to proxy a Craft CMS site hosted on apache into an existing site

Tags: craft3, nginx

I have a Craft CMS blog site that is hosted on an apache web server. I would like to proxy that site to my Flask-based web app at http://example.com/blog/ where http://example.com is the main URL for the app. http://example.com/blog/ does not have any application routes so it is a safe URL to use.

Here is the relevant part of my NGINX config.

```
    location ^~ /blog/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://cms.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        auth_basic "Stealth Mode - Coming Soonish";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

My problem is that I get the following Template Not Found error.

```
    Template not found: blog
```

Any ideas how to fix this? The fact that I am getting a Craft error indicates to me that the issue is a craft config issue, but I am not ruling out some sort of nginx error config error.

Comment: Update. I have pretty much eliminated Nginx as the issue here since I was able to proxy a static site through. So I think I am looking at a Craftcms issue here.

Comment: In your case, when you hit http://cms.example.com directly (outside of nginx) what happens? That's the blog "home page" more or less?

Comment: When I hit cms.example.com directly the site renders properly but as cms.example.com and not cms.example.com/blog. The difference is that I am trying to reverse proxy it under example.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue. The issue was a conflict in the craft. I had the wrong URL in Settings > Sites: [This site has its own base URL] should be clicked and the correct URL should be provided. When the site is live I will come back and post more information to demonstrate the result.